# Область видимости переменных класса в PHP

Tags: php, классы

Есть такой php-файл с классом:

class.php:

```
class classTest
{
    private $password;

    private function showName($foo)
    {
        $password= "QWERTY";
        $bar = $password. " == " . $foo;

        return $bar;
    }

    private function hideName($foo1)
    {

        $password= "QWERTY";
        $bar1 = $foo1 . " !!!! " . $password;

        return $bar1;
    }
}
```

Он делает всякую ерунду, но это не важно.

Смысл в том, что в обоих функциях используется переменная $password и ее содержимое идентично.

Скажите, КАК обозначить ее ОДИН РАЗ где-то в классе таким образом, чтобы она была видна только в функциях этого класса, но не была видна в php-файле, в котором инклюдится данный файл с классом?

Не могу понять, где в каких случаях ставится public, где private... Голову сломал, прошу просто показать рабочий и правильный пример, чтобы хотя бы понять, как оно должно работать.

Comment: При создании экземпляра класса `classTest`, переменная `$password` не будет видна. Так происходит и в C#, и в Java...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы в функциях *showName* и *hideName* вводите локальную переменную *$password*, которая не доступна остальным функциям класса.

Для того, чтобы использовать поле $password объекта во всех его функциях нужно:

1. Объявить переменную в классе (что Вы правильно сделали)
2. Обращаться к этой переменной через объект $this класса (что Вы сделали неправильно)

Вот правильный вариант:

```
class classTest
{
    private $password;

    private function showName($foo)
    {
        $this->password= "QWERTY";
        $bar = $this->password. " == " . $foo;

        return $bar;
    }

    private function hideName($foo1)
    {

        $this->password= "QWERTY";
        $bar1 = $foo1 . " !!!! " . $this->password;

       return $bar1;
    }
}
```

Модификатор **private** означает, что эта обращаться к этой переменной можно будет только **внутри нашего класса** (в нашем случае это функции класса *showName* и *hideName*).

Т.е. если мы создадит объект класса

```
$a = new classTest();
```

то у нас **не получится** посмотреть и изменить его переменную вне класса

Если же мы ставим **public**, мы **можем** изменять и получать переменную класса вне функций этого класса:

```
echo $a->password;     // Выводим пароль
$a->password = '12345' // Меняем пароль
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Обозначай Private. 
А вообще-то мануал по PHP еще не закрыли :) Там много примеров и все очень подробно расписано. 
Пройдись по примерам и все станет ясно, это ведь основы, которые желательно знать наизусть для разработчика
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: Спасибо! Очень много манов перечитал, но почему-то именно по вашей ссылке зашел и сразу все встало на свои места! Иногда так бывает))